# Why is $a \equiv (a$mod$m)$mod$m$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

I tried doing an example where $a = 10$ and $m = 4$ but I get this

$10 \equiv  (10 mod 4)  mod 4$

$10 \equiv 2 mod 4$

$10 \equiv 0$ ??

Is that logic not correct? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change the title It's weird looking

Comment: MathJax hint:  if you put slashes before functions, you get the right font and spacing.  For mod, \pmod get the modulus plus puts it all in parentheses, so 10 \pmod 4 gives $10 \pmod 4$. bmod omits the parentheses, so 10 \bmod 4 gives $10 \bmod 4$.   If the modulus is multiple characters, put it in braces.

Answer (score 1):

If the percent sign is the modulus operator, as it is in some programming languages, $2\%4=2,$ not $0$ so $10 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and all is well

Comment: I edited the title it should be updated now to a is equivalent to (amodm)modm

Answer (score 0):

Note $\ a = \bar a + q\,m,\,\ $ for $\,\bar a = (a\bmod m),\, $ by dividing $\,a\,$ by $\,m\ $ [Division Algorithm]

Thus $\ a\equiv \bar a \pmod m\ $ by definition, $ $ i.e. since $\ m\mid a-\bar a\ $ by above.